# TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

Tags: node.js

Written in node.js file

The function is returning the error:

> Returns the ACE occupation exhibit identifier

**Example of originalID**: 46R-002-30BroadJour12_01-12_11

**Expected output**: 46R-002

```
/*This function is returning the error:
Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined*/
function splitID(originalID){
  var aceid = originalID.substring(0,7);
  return aceid;
}

//1. Get the ace exhibit occupation id for each of them and put it in a parallel array.
for (var row in values) {
  //split the 5th column using our function
  var output = splitID(row[4]);
  var result = getOccupation(output);
  //now we add the split output to our occupation array.
  occupationsToInsert.append(result);
}
```

Comment: const values = [
  ['COMM', '1200', 'INTRO MASS COMMUNICATION', 'M024', '46R-002-30BroadJour12_01-12_11'],.....];

Answer (score 0):

If you may refer to the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) at MDN, it advises against using `for...in` for looping over the arrays because it does not give consistent values on return. It rather iterates on the `enumerable` properties of the concerned object passed to it.

In other words, `for (var row in values)` would not iterate over each individual rows as expected, but rather the enumerable properties of the `values` list.

So, for your const array, you can find the enumerable properties by simply doing

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(values)
```

which would return you the following list :

```
["0", "length"]
```

You're essentially trying to access the fourth element of this array which doesn't exist, and thereby it is undefined, causing the error you observe.

Answer (score -1):

The error is telling you the exact problem: `originalID` is undefined. In your `for` loop, `row[4]` is resulting in an undefined value. Verify your `values` array contains what you are expecting.